# Problems with entrypoints (from other packages) when installing package through pip

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

Trying to install a package, for example, `pytorch`

`pip install torch` / `pip install -U torch`

And I'm greeted with this

```
Collecting torch
  Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aissy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-35x5kco9\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aissy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-35x5kco9\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\aissy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35x5kco9\torch\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\aissy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35x5kco9\torch\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2811, in get_entry_map
        ep_map = self._ep_map
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2769, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _ep_map

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\aissy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35x5kco9\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 133, in _install_setup_requires
        (k, v) for k, v in attrs.items()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 444, in __init__
        for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 656, in <genexpr>
        for entry in dist.get_entry_map(group).values()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2814, in get_entry_map
        self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2516, in parse_map
        maps[group] = cls.parse_group(group, lines, dist)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2494, in parse_group
        ep = cls.parse(line, dist)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2472, in parse
        raise ValueError(msg, src)
    ValueError: ("EntryPoint must be in 'name=module:attrs [extras]' format but got this instead json-server=json-server.cli:main", 'json-server=json-server.cli:main')
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
PS C:\Windows\system32> py -m pip install -u nltk                                                                                         
Usage:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: -u
PS C:\Windows\system32> py -m pip install -U nltk                                                                                         Collecting nltk
  Using cached nltk-3.5.zip (1.4 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aissy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d1oaxx5q\\nltk\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aissy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d1oaxx5q\\nltk\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\aissy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1oaxx5q\nltk\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\aissy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1oaxx5q\nltk\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2811, in get_entry_map
        ep_map = self._ep_map
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2769, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _ep_map

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\aissy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1oaxx5q\nltk\setup.py", line 112, in <module>
        entry_points=console_scripts,
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 133, in _install_setup_requires
        (k, v) for k, v in attrs.items()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 444, in __init__
        for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 656, in <genexpr>
        for entry in dist.get_entry_map(group).values()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2814, in get_entry_map
        self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2516, in parse_map
        maps[group] = cls.parse_group(group, lines, dist)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2494, in parse_group
        ep = cls.parse(line, dist)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2472, in parse
        raise ValueError(msg, src)
    ValueError: ("EntryPoint must be in 'name=module:attrs [extras]' format but got this instead json-server=json-server.cli:main", 'json-server=json-server.cli:main')
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
PS C:\Windows\system32> py -m pip install pip                                                                                             Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages (20.0.2)
PS C:\Windows\system32> py -m pip install pip==20.0.1                                                                                     Collecting pip==20.0.1
  Using cached pip-20.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Uninstalling pip-20.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.0.2
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.7.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-20.0.1
PS C:\Windows\system32> py -m pip install pip==20.0.2                                                                                     Collecting pip==20.0.2
  Using cached pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-20.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.0.1
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.7.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-20.0.2
PS C:\Windows\system32> py -m pip install torch                                                                                           Collecting torch
  Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aissy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1ii8iy6m\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aissy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1ii8iy6m\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\aissy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ii8iy6m\torch\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\aissy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ii8iy6m\torch\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2811, in get_entry_map
        ep_map = self._ep_map
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2769, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _ep_map

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\aissy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ii8iy6m\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 133, in _install_setup_requires
        (k, v) for k, v in attrs.items()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 444, in __init__
        for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 656, in <genexpr>
        for entry in dist.get_entry_map(group).values()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2814, in get_entry_map
        self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2516, in parse_map
        maps[group] = cls.parse_group(group, lines, dist)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2494, in parse_group
        ep = cls.parse(line, dist)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2472, in parse
        raise ValueError(msg, src)
    ValueError: ("EntryPoint must be in 'name=module:attrs [extras]' format but got this instead json-server=json-server.cli:main", 'json-server=json-server.cli:main')
    -----------------------------------------
```

As what I believe `json-server`'s Entrypoint is causing the issue. As far as I'm aware, `json-server` is not a python package but a CLI tool.

I'm assuming the `-` in `json-server=json-server.cli:main` as from what I read from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283929/why-do-i-keep-getting-this-message-when-installing-saying-entrypoint-must-be-in)

What can I do about it?

Comment: I assume it's about this project [json-server.py](https://pypi.org/project/json-server.py/). So I would start by [raising the issue to the maintainers of that project](https://github.com/gera2ld/json-server.py/issues).

Comment: Is this project _json-server.py_ really needed? Did you install it yourself? Is it supposed to be a dependency of another project? Maybe just uninstall it.

Answer (score 3):

There're two problems in the package.

1. The main importable directory is named [`json-server`](https://github.com/gera2ld/json-server.py/tree/c816d307c6aab624b5fa15b852c38d8477cc0f94/json-server). It's a bug, `-` is forbidden in Python names. It must be renamed to `json_server`.
2. The script is [declared](https://github.com/gera2ld/json-server.py/blob/c816d307c6aab624b5fa15b852c38d8477cc0f94/pyproject.toml#L25-L26) using that forbidden module. It must be fixed as

```python
[tool.poetry.scripts]
json-server = "json_server.cli:main"
```

Please [report these bugs](https://github.com/gera2ld/json-server.py/issues).

*Upd*. Fixed in https://github.com/gera2ld/json-server.py/commit/999349683d3f0ac09821a9882d1f947848edb526